# How can I make the server not log (store) user IP and User Agent?

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I want to provide privacy to my visitors by not logging the IP or useragent.

I have tried to use the .htaccess for this but can't get it to work, for example with

**SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "*" dontlog**

This resulted in a 500 error of course. I am a bit of a novice, so not very familiar with syntax etc..

What is the best way to instruct the server to not log request for any visitor, with htaccess or any other way?

Appreciate any feedback / ideas.

Cheers,

Fred

- CentOS 6 with Plesk Panel 10
- 1and1.co.uk host, using Server L 4 Linux Standard
- Using php for website

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the main virtual host configuration in Apache, instead of specifying the `AccessLog` or `ErrorLog` path, do:

```
ErrorLog /dev/null
AccessLog /dev/null
```

But you said you were at 1&1 which is normally a shared hosting provider. According to the Apache documentation, you cannot override `ErrorLog`, `AccessLog` or `CustomLog` from the `.htaccess`

Comment: Thanks Steven. I have a dedicated server but only need to do this for one domain on the server. I think I may get a second dedicated server for this and do what you suggest. Much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the setting.php , try adding

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']='0.0.0.0';
```

It may not be right method, hope it can be a Plan B :)

Comment: Cheers mate, I am playing around with this now to see if I can get it to work.